# Why does "youtube-dl" keep downloading high quality videos though I tell it not to do so?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I use the following line, indicating strictly to download the best video format with height less than or equal to 720p (using `bestvideo[height<=720,ext=mp4]` option), but it still downloads video with 1080p height. Couldn't figure out the problem... What am I doing wrong, can someone give me a hand?

```
youtube-dl --ignore-errors --playlist-start 1 --playlist-end 5 --yes-playlist --autonumber-start 1 --format "bestvideo[height<=720,ext=mp4]+bestaudio[height<=720,ext=m4a]" --output "%(playlist)s/%(autonumber)03d - %(title)s.%(ext)s" "video_url"
```

Command line simplified:

```
youtube-dl --format "bestvideo[height<=720,ext=mp4]+bestaudio[height<=720,ext=m4a]" "video_url"
```

System: Kubuntu-20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot combine filters with commas.

Your simplified command should be:

```
youtube-dl --format "bestvideo[height<=720][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]" "video_url"
```